# jquery/javascript are not working inside ng-view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to achieve SPA with help angular route provide for that i'm using ng-view for injecting the views. in one page i'ave a jquery datatable where i need to get the index of row selected by using jquery. but this is not happing inside ng-view. i tried by using directives also but no luck.
can someone help me in this

**Home.html**

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
 </table>
```

Get Selected Rows

**Controller.Js:**

```
app.controller("HomeController", function ($scope, $http,$window) {
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "test.json",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": null },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "extn" },
        { "data": "start_date" },
        { "data": "salary" }
    ],
    columnDefs: [{
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets: 0
    }],
    select: {
        style: 'os',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    order: [[1, 'asc']]
});
$scope.$broadcast('dataloaded');
$scope.Customers = $("example").DataTable().data;
console.log("Result: ", $scope.Customers.length);
$scope.GetDetails = function () {
    var table = $("example").DataTable();
    var rowid = table.row(this).index();
    alert(rowid);
};

$scope.GetRowID = function () {
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        console.log("inside");
        debugger;
        var table = $("#example").DataTable();
        alert('Row index: ' + table.row(this).index());
    });

};

$scope.init();
```

Comment: jQuery plugin code belongs inside a directive. Suggest you use a datatables module for this so as not to re-invent the wheel

Comment: Please use this [link](http://ui-grid.info/).Its far better than the jQuery one  and easy to handle.

Comment: The first step to solving a problem is to describe the problem. "didn't work" and "no luck: are not problem descriptions. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: the functionality i'm expecting is on button click the selected rows in the datagrid has to delete. this is working fine when i invoke the html page without using ng-view but when i integrate and inject the html then the button click event itself is not working.